# Silverlight MultiScaleTileSource (or DeepZoom) - wrap dateline possible (limitless horizontal panning)?

Tags: date, silverlight, word-wrap, deepzoom

I am wondering whether it is possible to implement wrapping of the dateling (or wrapping the map around as you pan off the 'edge' ) using the MultiScaleTileSource? Or any of the implementation that use it? DeepZoom? DeepEarth?

I really need this functionality in SilverLight (and offline mode as well - so Bing Maps Control won't do here).

So I was wondering if anyone was successful in implementing the wrapping of the dateline using that control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution for this problem:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/HDViewSL/

HDViewSL provides this functionality.